# Out of 2 jQuery plugins I use in a form only 1 works

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a web form and I want to use a plugin for validation and another plugin for accordion. I can't get them to work together. Always only the 2nd plugin works. I think the 2nd overwrites something the 1st uses.

Here are 2 samples:

http://www.mojpodstanar.com/JQUERY_PROBLEM/validation_ok.html - here validation works accordion doesn't

http://www.mojpodstanar.com/JQUERY_PROBLEM/accordion_ok.html - here accordion works validation doesn't

Notice in the source code that in the first case the validation plugin is added as second while in the second case the accordion. Always the last added works.

How can I make them work both?

Comment: Not a true answer: I would start by removing one of the TWO jquery libraries you included. I see jQuery 1.2.3b - New Wave Javascript and jQuery v1.6.4.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only include jQuery once in page, and before any of the plugins. Your assumption about "over write" is correct

Comment: Thank You all for the replies, I included only once and now it works. Should have figured out myself.

Comment: You should accept this answer as @charlietfl was the first to reply.

Answer (score 1):

In line 10 you add a reference to jQuery core and later you overwrite it in line 32. So whats happend is that you first add jQuery. you register a plugin and later you Overwrite jQuery so there is no plugin and when you add the last plguin.

So remove the last jQuery reference in line 32

Comment: Thank You all for the replies, I included only once and now it works. Should have figured out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Only include jQuery once and Combined these:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
  {
    // simple accordion
    jQuery('#list1a').accordion();
  });
</script>
```

So it'll look like:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function ()
  {
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();

    // simple accordion
    jQuery('#list1a').accordion();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You all for the replies, I included only once and now it works. Should have figured out myself.